# Changing the if statement

Tags: c, if-statement

I was playing with my code and started wondering if this change from:

```
if(array[index] == 0)
```

to this:

```
if(!array[index] != 0)
```

could affect any code or does it just do the same thing and I don't need to worry about how I write this?

Comment: in shot: avoid double negation... it's usually the less readable form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are different conditions. `!` has higher precedence than `==` therefore, `!array[index] != 0` is equivalent to `(!array[index]) != 0`.
Equivalent to `array[index] == 0` is `!(array[index] != 0)`.

Comment: In the context of C and assuming `array[index]` is an integer, it would be logically equivalent which is all that really matters.

Answer (score 2):

Consider some truth tables, assuming `array` is an array of integers:

```
array[index] | array[index] == 0 | !array[index] | !array[index] != 0
0            | T                 | 1             | T
1            | F                 | 0             | F
non-zero     | F                 | 0             | F
```

Both expressions are logically equivalent so either one should work as you might expect.

*But*, you should write it in the first form. You clearly knew the first form works.  Anyone who would see it would understand it works.  But the second, you had your doubts because it wasn't clear. It's unreadable. You should always go for what is clear over what isn't. Don't try to be clever with things that should be simple.

Answer (score 1):

They are different. If you want to have it as like `if(array[index] == 0)` then you need `if(!(array[index] != 0))`

Answer (score 1):

They are different. If you're trying to change the `==` to using `!`, then it would be `(array[index] !=0)` where you check the condition when the value at the index is not equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

I've just checked a simple function to see what happens:

```
int matrix (int *array, int n)
{
  int c = 0;
  int index = 0;

  for (index=0;index<n;index++)
    if (array[index]==0)
      c++;

  return c;
}
```

BTW: you don't specify what type of elements `array` has. I assume they are `ints`, but if they are `floats` or `doubles`, that might change the following argument:

No matter what I change the if line to. I've tried:

```
if (array[index]==0)

if (!(array[index]!=0))

if (!array[index])
```

After compiling this with:

```
    gcc -O0 -c -S -m32 ifs.c
```

The three options generate the same assembly code:

```
        movl    (%eax), %eax
        testl   %eax, %eax
        jne     .L3
        addl    $1, -4(%ebp)
.L3:
        addl    $1, -8(%ebp)
```

If I enable optimizations:

```
    gcc -O3 -c -S -m32 ifs.c
```

The three versions generate this code:

```
        cmpl    $0, (%edx)
        leal    1(%eax), %ecx
        jne     .L4
        movl    %ecx, %eax
.L4:
        addl    $4, %edx
```

So it doesn't really matter how you write it; the compiler will infer the same meaning and generate the same code, so write it the most legible way to ease maintentace.

---

For floating point numbers, there is indeed a difference between the code compiled with -O0 and -O3. For floating point numbers some options exists, as code for SSE2 can be generated instead of code for the math coprocessor.